# Wrapping json results in <pre> tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make my own API for my discord bot and i noticed the response looks like this:
[image: Showing JSON code in font Times New Roman]
font probably **times new roman** because it is not wrapped in a `<pre>` tag.

But when I DO wrap it in a `<pre>` tag to make it look like this:
[image: Showing JSON Code in font Monospace](font monospace)
the contents have the tags in it...

For example these are the contents that are grabbed:

```
<pre>{"success":true,"type":"sha256","string":"Hello friend","hash":"ad7c4d7f20d11015260cd4609df255c99ebef944f59110167f2ff62a2c750072"}</pre>
```

The code:

```
<?php
    $json_array = json_encode(range(0,10));
    echo "<pre>{$json_array}</pre>";
```

I also tried this with no avail:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $json_array = json_encode(range(0,10));
    echo $json_array;
```

How would I go about getting the json wrapped in the `<pre>` tag without it affecting how it grabs the content? I feel like I have looked everywhere but can't find a thing. I know it can be done because an API I use gets wrapped in the `<pre>` tag and doesn't have a problem retrieving the json.

Comment: If you do want it more readable try `echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: Because by wrapping your JSON in html tags, you invalidate the JSON response.

Comment: Perhaps give an example URL of an endpoint that wraps the json in html tags.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are not adding a JSON header to the response.  If you do so, a browser such as Firefox lets me inspect the JSON output.  Try this before your echo/output, and don't add the html tags.  `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and make sure you have NO empty spaces above your `<?php` tag!

***That was the problem here, a simple empty space/line above the `<?php` tag.***

So my second code block should've worked, had I not left an empty line above the `<?php` tag at the top of the PHP file. *e.g:*

**Before (output.php):**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $json_array = json_encode(range(0,10));
    echo $json_array;
?>
```

**After (output.php):**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $json_array = json_encode(range(0,10));
    echo $json_array;
?>
```